# django-filter not working with django-rest-framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filters

I'm using `Django 2.0`, `Django REST Framework` and [`Django Filters`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html) to filter the queryset.

I have installed `django-filters` and added to `INSTALLED_APPS` as `django_filters`.

The settings file has

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',)
}
```

and the view class is like

```
class AmountGivenViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AmountGivenSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    filterset_fields = ('contact__id',)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = AmountGiven.objects.filter(
            contact__user=self.request.user
        )
        query = self.request.query_params.get('q', None)

        if query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(transaction_number=query) |
                Q(comment__contains=query) |
                Q(amountreturned__transaction_number=query) |
                Q(amountreturned__comment__contains=query)
            )

        return queryset
```

**AmountGiven** model has a foreign key to **contact** and thus want to filter based on **contact_id**.

Now when I try the following URL

```
https://example.com/api/amount-given/?contact__id=3634de36-181c-4414-93fc-f08e3d70f1e3
```

It does not filter the result and returns all **AmountGiven** records.

Comment: Does any other filter has same problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing filterset_fields for "filter_fields" like this:

```
class AmountGivenViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AmountGivenSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    filterset_fields = ('contact__id',)
```

Comment: The official django-filter doc suggest us to use `filterset_fields`

Comment: Just a heads up - the `filter_fields` parameter has been deprecated and renamed to `filterset_fields`.